# .htaccess URL rewrite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite an old url structure, mysite.com/blog/my-blog-post, to a new URL structure mysite.com/blog/post/my-blog-post. Currently, I have this rule in my .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /blog/post/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is outputing mysite.com/blog/post/post/post/post/post/post/post/.../my-blog-post.

It seems like my rewrite keeps mataching and therefore rewrites again. And again. And again. I've tried to add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But that did not help. I'm wondering if it's becuase the blog posts are from CMS/Database as opposed to actual files being pointed to.

To make this a little more tricky with the new structure for the blog, I have categories located mysite.com/blog/my-category-name. I also have mysite.com/blog/author/author-name. I don't want nor do I need to rewrite these URLs. Is this doable? Should I add the word "category" to my category URL to make this easier?

Just as a reference here are the additional rewrite rules in my .htaccess:

```
# For more awesome .htaccess rules and optimisations
# checkout the HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess files
# https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess

# Although highly unlikely, your host may have +FollowSymLinks enabled at the root level,
# yet disallow its addition in .htaccess; in which case,
# adding +FollowSymLinks will break your setup (probably a 500 error),
# so just remove it, and your rules should work fine.
Options +FollowSymlinks

# EE 404 page for missing pages
# ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/{ee:404}

# Simple 404 for missing files
<FilesMatch "(\.jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|css|js|flv)$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "File Not Found"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

# Blog redirects
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /blog/post/$1 [R=301,L]
# RedirectMatch ^/blog/$ /blog/post/$1 [R=301,L] --> Didn't work

# Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
# includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or Git.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

# remove the www - Uncomment to activate
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Remove the trailing slash to paths without an extension
# Uncomment to activate
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a specific check that the next path node isn't `/post/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/post
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /blog/post/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This worked great. I also added checks for `/category` and `/author`